# How can I include transformed dll to an Azure deployment

Tags: azure

For my Worker role I run a custom task to modify the dll. However, when I use VS to publish the project to Azure the original binary is deployed and not the modified dll. Why is this happening? How to include the modified binary in the package from within VS
This is with sdk+tools v1.6

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean by custom task? Is this a post build task or something else?

Comment: yes that's a post build task.

Answer (score 2):

A possible workaround that I see, is to extract all the code/logic that requires assmebly modification in a separate class library project. Do the custom post-build modification on the class library.

In your worker add reference to that class library. If it also does not work when you add the reference as a project reference, then just copy the resulted modified assembly in a common external references folder for the solution, and add the reference from there (just browse to the final assembly).

I don't know the nature of your modification, but I think that if you cave all your "private" code in a separate class library it will be enough. As the worker implementation will just be calling a "Run()" or similar method of your class library, inside the Run() method of the RoleEntryPoint.